# Submenu hover is not working on internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover

Plz help me ,

I have a menu which is absolutely positioned and its submenus are also same positioned...

The link of my website is :- http://pgdermatologos.com

The Problem is that , when i hover over the menu , the submenu appears but as i leave the hover from menu and hover over the submenu , it disappears.

I have done the submenu's "display:none" in default and on hover of the menus's li , i have done the submenu's "display:block".

Its working fine in Chrome and other browsers  but not working in internet explorer.

Please help me ,

The link of my website is :- http://pgdermatologos.com

Comment: Thanks for the response 
Its not working on IE 7,8,9 and 10

Comment: Try setting a background for the submenu.

Comment: I am not getting your problem can you please post a screen shot?

Comment: The submenu gets displayed if you hover over a menu item, but if you hover of the submenu, it disappears.

Comment: please give a fiddle link with your code and css.

Comment: try this CSS: `#pg_nav ul li a:hover ul{display:block}` but you better create a fiddle if you want better answers.

Comment: Thank you all for you replies ,
I will give you jsfiddle link shortly .....

Comment: here is my js fiddle link :-  http://jsfiddle.net/hfshakir52/Sxs6b/

Comment: and live website is  :- http://pgdermatologos.com/

please run this website on internet explorer and try to figure out the problem

Comment: Hi again !

Please hepl me if anyone can ?

Comment: In google chrome and other browser , everything is working properly but only in ie , the submenu are disappearing on leaving mouse from the menu li ..

What is the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add **!important** to your **.sub-menu** absolute position

```
.sub-menu {position: absolute !important;}
```

Comment: Hi Naseer !
I have done .sub-menu {position: absolute !important; } ,

but it didn't worked ...
http://pgdermatologos.com/   please run this website on internet explorer and try to figure out the problem ,

Comment: when i remove the img tags inside the <div id="target"> menu hover is work correctly, it seems images have a problem  but i still try to find out :)

Answer (score 0):

In IE the document type declaration *must* be at the very first line of the file, and it must not preceed by *any* characters.

You have five empty lines before the doctype declaration on your page. Just remove them, and your page should work. Actually the linked fiddle works exactly in the same way in IE10 and FF22.

Comment: Thanks Teemu for rplying !

I have removed the empty lines but still it is not working .
Can you look it again please .

Comment: Like I said, the fiddle works in the same way in both IE10 and FF22. Please check if there's some differece between the fiddle code and your production code.